# setting up vulkan for code::blocks via glfw or lunarg

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks, glfw, vulkan

I have code::blocks and a spare evening, would like to put my hands on vulkan. Now on windows 7.

I'm having troubles finding any documentation/tutorials nor the libraries to work in codeblocks. I have glfw 3.2 but it requires a vulkan library and headers as well to work with it (`#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN`) otherwise it rightfully complains about a missing `vulkan/vulkan.h`. Also installed LunarG, but can't find any recognizable libraries in the package that i could link via the linker settings in the usual way.

My code right now is straightforward:

```
...
#include <GL/glu.h>
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glfwInit();
    return glfwVulkanSupported();
}
```

with `-lglu32 -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lgdi32`

Basically all i think i need is a library to link to but can't find any on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Using the old GLU library may not be a good idea with Vulkan
2. Instal the LunarG SDK.
3. Set additional include directory in your IDE project: `$VULKAN_SDK/Include` (`VULKAN_SDK` is an env variable with a path to root of the SDK).
4. Do not link against OpenGL if you are only going to use Vulkan.
5. Code::Blocks is g++ or clang based right? Link against the `vulkan-1.dll`. `-lvulkan-1` should suffice, because the path should be in PATH. Otherwise provide the path with `-L` — it is in `$WINDIR/System32` (for x64 and x32 OS) and in `$WINDIR/SysWOW64` (for x32 app on x64 OS).

`vulkan-1.dll` is installed there by drivers and by the SDK also.

Comment: The original idea was to switch between opengl and vulkan on the fly, but nothing is preventing me to just split into two executables. I linked the path to the `bin32/vulkan-1.lib` in the sdk and that worked. 800 lines later i managed to get a triangle to pop :/

Comment: Linking to the *.lib is perhaps the preferred thing. It just always gives me linker errors in g++ so I suggested the *.dll instead.